# Trying to add ErrorDocuments to HTACCESS but having Rewrite conflicts

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having a bit of trouble with this one. I am looking to have any error code that a user gets (400,401,403,404,500) route to a page called error.php in the root directory.

I've researched what I could online about it, but to no avail have I found any luck. My problem is a bit more unique and my knowledge of an htaccess file is sadly basic.

Here is the code:

```
## Route error pages
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php

Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^item/(.*)$ ./itemlookup.php?search=$1
RewriteRule ^recipe/(.*)$ ./recipelookup.php?search=$1
RewriteRule ^secret/recipe/(.*)$ ./secret/recipelookup.php?search=$1
RewriteRule ^api/json/idbyname/(.*)$ ./api/json/getidbyname.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/csv/idbyname/(.*)$ ./api/csv/getidbyname.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/json/item/(.*)$ ./api/json/items.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/csv/item/(.*)$ ./api/csv/items.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/json/forge/(.*)$ ./api/json/mysticforge.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/csv/forge/(.*)$ ./api/csv/mysticforge.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/json/history/(.*)$ ./api/json/tradehistory.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/csv/history/(.*)$ ./api/csv/tradehistory.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/json/history-daily/(.*)$ ./api/json/tradehistorydaily.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/csv/history-daily/(.*)$ ./api/csv/tradehistorydaily.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/json/recipe/(.*)$ ./api/json/craftingrecipes.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/csv/recipe/(.*)$ ./api/csv/craftingrecipes.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/json/exchange/(.*)$ ./api/json/gemexchange.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/csv/exchange/(.*)$ ./api/csv/gemexchange.php [QSA]

#Gzip Compression, Saves on bandwidth
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf image/svg+xml
</ifmodule>
#End Gzip

## EXPIRES CACHING - 1 Month ##
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|woff|woff2|svg)$">
ExpiresActive on 
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(jquery-1\.9\.1\.min\.js)$">
ExpiresActive on 
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</FilesMatch>
```

My users will see existing pages correctly. But any what would be 404 page errors and it's likeness will reroute to a 500 internal server error (without error page routing).

So in a nutshell the ErrorDocument lines aren't working. All help is certainly appreciated!

Sincerely,
RebornGeek

Comment: so your point is when your user reach error.php then {500 internal server error} comes

Comment: did you check your apache error log to see what is causing the 500 error. I would start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Keep `.php` adding rule at last.
2. Add `.php` only if matching file exists.

Replace your rules with this:

```
## Route error pages
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php

Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(index|error)\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^item/(.*)$ itemlookup.php?search=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^recipe/(.*)$ recipelookup.php?search=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^secret/recipe/(.*)$ secret/recipelookup.php?search=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/json/idbyname/(.*)$ api/json/getidbyname.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/csv/idbyname/(.*)$ api/csv/getidbyname.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/json/item/(.*)$ api/json/items.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/csv/item/(.*)$ api/csv/items.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/json/forge/(.*)$ api/json/mysticforge.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/csv/forge/(.*)$ api/csv/mysticforge.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/json/history/(.*)$ api/json/tradehistory.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/csv/history/(.*)$ api/csv/tradehistory.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/json/history-daily/(.*)$ api/json/tradehistorydaily.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/csv/history-daily/(.*)$ api/csv/tradehistorydaily.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/json/recipe/(.*)$ api/json/craftingrecipes.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/csv/recipe/(.*)$ api/csv/craftingrecipes.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/json/exchange/(.*)$ api/json/gemexchange.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/csv/exchange/(.*)$ api/csv/gemexchange.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

#Gzip Compression, Saves on bandwidth
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf image/svg+xml
</ifmodule>
#End Gzip
```